# How to Delete data after a certain amount of time in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I try that in nodejs

```
const recoverySchema = mongoose.Schema({
   recoveryId : {type: Number, unique: true},
   createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: 3600 },
},{ strict: false });
```

I expected removing data after 1 hour.

.. But data is removed at a unspecified time.

What is the problem?

Comment: "But data is removed at a unspecified time." what does that mean? It was removed but you do not know at what time? Was the index created?

Comment: It's mean that  is not removed at exactly one hour. It seems to be removed in one minute.

Comment: Yes because the process runs every minute. "The background task that removes expired documents runs every 60 seconds. As a result, documents may remain in a collection during the period between the expiration of the document and the running of the background task."

Comment: If so, how do I delete it after one hour?

Comment: Can you try the same thing without mongoose and see if the base mongoDB TTL index works for you first? Just create the index then the record and see if it will be deleted after 2 mins for example. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

Comment: I Add "recoverySchema.index({ createAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds : 180 });" and solved that

Comment: awesome. So then you can add the answer I guess to the question etc.